# Database SQL query check validity of query

Tags: sql, database

Suppose we have 2 relations Teacher(Name,Class,Age) and Student(Name,Class,Age).

Suppose this is the relation table:

```
Student  Name  Class  Age         Teacher  Name        Class     Age 
         John  A1     12                   Mr.Smith    A1        30
         Mike  A1     8                    Mr.Newmann  A2        29
         Harry A2     11
```

Is this SQL code valid:

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Age>10 AND Class IN(SELECT Class FROM Teacher WHERE 
Name='Mrs.Smith')
```

Okay lets work backwards.

The `(SELECT Class  FROM Teacher WHERE  Name='Mrs.Smith')` will return

```
    Class     

    A1
```

So the result will be

```
Name    Class    Age 
John    A1       12
```

Am I correct?

Comment: Cancel what I wrote originally. You are correct.

Comment: It's correct. But you should also try to JOIN the tables.

Comment: BTW, never store age. People become older every year, and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.

Comment: Tip: the best way to learn SQL is practice, practice, practice. If you have no dbms installed. you can try your queries at https://dbfiddle.uk/.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment for some reason so I'll add an answer.  Yes, you are correct.  However, Age>10 is an unnecessary condition because you only have one row with Mrs. Smith.

Comment: If I didnt have Age>10 then the querry would give a result of both Mike and John.